# how to check a value and operate booleans with it from firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this setted on my firebase account.

[todo collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSfm0.png)

[percent collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQbsC.png)

I want that when a task is added, the task is marked as true, and 10 points are added in the "value" field of the "Percent" collection. My problem is that when the button that calls this function is pressed, the task keeps running as many times as the button is pressed. How can I solve it? I have tried various community contributed solutions and I think this is where the error lies. Thanks!

```
Future completTask(uid) async {
    await todosCollection.doc(uid).update({
      "isComplet": true
            });
            if (porcentaje > 0){
    percentcollection.doc('percentage').update({

"value": porcentaje -= 10
    });}else{porcentaje = 0;}

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the isComplet field is false or true first and then make the call, so if it is false then you will complete the call else you should return

```
Future completTask(String uid) async {
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await todosCollection.doc(uid).get();
  if (snapshot.data()['isComplet'] == true) {
    return;
  } else {
    await todosCollection.doc(uid).update({
      "isComplet": true
    });
    if (porcentaje > 0){
       percentcollection.doc('percentage').update({
         "value": porcentaje -= 10
       });
    }else{ 
       porcentaje = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I was stucked on this for days!!

Comment: It was my pleasure to help you